# How to fix the arteria contact form error in django cms?

Tags: python, django

I just recently installed and added an arteria contact from the Django cms marketplace. The only thing I didn't setup all the way as the e-mail configurations. 
Anyways, when I added an input form to test it out, I got a connection error:
ConnectionRefusedError at /en/contact/
[Errno 111] Connection refused
then I get this at the bottom at line 57

```
47       
48      </div>
49  
50    </div>
51  </nav>
52  <div class="container-fluid">
53          <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
54            <div class="col-md-4">
55              {% block sideleft %}
56              <ul id="events-upcoming">
57  

      {% placeholder "side1" %}



58               </ul>
59               <ul id="events-past">
60                {% placeholder "side2" %}
61              </ul>
62              {% endblock sideleft %}
63            </div>
64          <div class="col-md-8">
65            
66            {% block content %}
67
```

Comment: "Connection refused" isn't necessarily a programming error. It sounds like it's attempting to connect to a mail server and is unable to do so. Have you configured an appropriate mail server? Can you connect to it using a normal mail client?

Comment: well this is my first time working with django and python so I don't know to setup the mail server. I can't find any good tutorials that can help me

Comment: Oh I got it working. I figured it out.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Can you either post details of what you did as an answer, then accept it (so others can benefit from your solution), or delete this question (so others don't come here to try and solve something that's already been fixed). Thanks

Comment: EMAIL_USE_TLS =True
EMAIL_HOST ='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT =465
EMAIL_HOST_USER =' '
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ='''

Comment: Thanks. You may want to read this... http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. In short, use the Answer box below. Write a fully formed answer, then accept it. It becomes part of a reference library for others. All the best.